# What is this circular symbol on my SD card?

Tags: certification

I have bought a SD card, same as in the picture below. I have found a completely new logo printed on that. I have searched on the internet for this logo, but didn't find anything.

Can anyone here tell me what's it?

Thank you.

[image: logo on SD card]

Comment: you can actually solve that question with a google image search, if you crop your SD card image to only show that icon.

Comment: I tried it and found only links to this SD card.

Comment: That's a new one on me... Charged Capacitor Warning? CMOS ESD maybe?

Comment: I tried that before posting it here, but found Canon EOS camera photos.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I always try things like that but it almost never works.  Most of the image matches are similar in color composition, but the actual shapes don't get picked up very well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have found answer on Google. It's a Japanese version of FCC mark. 
Radio equipment conformity certification.
See this [LINK!](http://www.telec.or.jp/eng/)

[image]

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you wish, but probably after a few hours after posting the question.

Comment: Yeah! I have to wait for 2 days :/